# How to get user contact email with MS Graph api

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

In order to test an application in a multitenant Azure AD setup, I've created a test tenant and some users directly to Azure AD with the Azure management panel UI. 
The application retrieves all users in the directory using Microsoft Graph api.

```
graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync()
```

These users have userPrincipalName property like mike@mytesttenant.onmicrosoft.com where as mail property is null. This is expected as the manually created tenant doesn't have office365 mail accounts.

But the Azure AD profile has two fields for setting additional email address:
[image]

Is there some way to read this information with the Graph Api?

Comment: Is this information is saved as extension for user? If yes, you can fetch using user's graph extension api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Microsoft Graph doesn't support getting the otherMails property that's used in Azure Active Directory to store (alternative) email addresses.

> **Status in Microsoft Graph (March 23, 2018)**
>   GA availability: See User for imAddresses and licenseDetails.
>   otherMails is still not available, but coming soon.

Source: [Microsoft Graph or Azure AD Graph](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2016/07/08/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/)